# Do I need same apple id on both xcode and physical iphone device to install app?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I want to install flutter app on iphone physical device. I have one confusion about apple id whether we need same apple id on both xcode and device or we can install on any iphone device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No.

we don't need the same apple id on Xcode and device you are running the flutter app.

**Xcode:**
We required a Team id(apple id or developer certificate, which is generated from the apple developer account and make sure you have the same bundle identifier on Xcode and developer certificate).

**iPhone:**
We can install app of any iPhone having different apple id.

- Click on Trust button that pop up for the first time
- Next after build Go to Setting-General-Click on Team id-Click on Trust

Next time we can run from flutter IDE itself in release mode or debug mode.

- for debug mode : flutter run
- for release mode : flutter run --release

Comment: Is developer account mandatory to run app on physical device?

Comment: Yes, and you need a professional profile certificate too or a developer certificate.

Comment: I don't think we need developer account just to install app in physical iPhone. As my concern, we  can't upload app in App store without developer account. My case is different and is I just want to install app on IPhone via connection cable. I know we have to enter Team Id in Xcode, that doesn't mean only developer account but also apple id can work.

Comment: check this https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/how-to-test-your-ios-application-on-a-real-device.html#:~:text=Open%20up%20a%20project%20in,%E2%8C%98R)%20run%20the%20application.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response for each of my doubt.

Comment: You can get away with just an Apple ID if your app is simple and does not need some special features (Push/ApplePay etc). Just sign in to Xcode with your AppleID and then you can install on device and test it out. But this profile would expire in a week or so. At least in the initial days you can do this. But if you do need those special features then yes you need to purchase a developer account